# Warning : Cannot find refence "x" in "None"

Tags: python, tkinter, warnings

I got a program that gives different values "button_url" to multiples buttons (here, the code is simplified using only one button), and when a specific button is clicked, his value gets transfered into the variable "final_url", which I want to do actions on (like downloading or else).

Here is the code :

---

```
root = Tk()
final_url = None

def on_button_click(text):
    global final_url
    final_url = text
    root.destroy()

button_url = "https://hello.com"

button = Button(root, command=lambda txt=button_url: 
on_button_click(txt))
button.pack() 

# there are many buttons, but here I simplified using only one

root.mainloop()

final_url.do_something() # "do_something()" is just an example
```

---

The line "final_url = None" is present because I kept getting the warning "name final_url can be undefined" on the line "site_url.download()".

But I get the Pycharm warning "Cannot find reference "do_something" in "None""

But surely, if the script runs correctly, the value of "final_url" (None) is replaced by the value of the button (which is surely not "None"), before the mainloop ends. I don't understaind how the value of final_url could possibly be "None" after the mainloop ends.

Comment: What if the button is never clicked?

Comment: well, it just waits for the user to click it, and the value stays to None inside the loop. I only want to do actions on final_url after the button is clicked and the window is closed (there are more tkinter windows to come after this one).

Comment: The warning is just telling you that it's _theoretically possible_ for that variable to still be `None` when the main loop ends, because the button was never clicked.  If you're confident that will never actually happen, feel free to ignore the warning.

Comment: Okay, I think ignoring it will not cause much trouble but anyways, thank for giving me your time and help.

Comment: The final line should probably be something like `if final_url is not None: final_url.do_something()`

Comment: Gives me other warnings ... The only solution I could find was to use classes, but I don't have this knowledge yet. Thanks a lot for your help anyways.